# Compiled insert in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Anyone please help How We can get **Compiled insert** in **CodeIgniter** of **insert_batch** query

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this:-

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name' ,
      'date' => 'My date'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name' ,
      'date' => 'Another date'
   )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```

For more information, read [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)